# Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision when using a local dependency

Tags: react-native, npm, jestjs, yarnpkg

I'm using a local module in `package.json` that also has `react-native` as a dependency.

In my APP `package.json`:

```
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0",
"react-native-services": "file:///Users/R01/Projects/react-native-services"
```

In  my `react-native-services` `package.json`:

```
"react": "16.4.1",
"react-native": "0.56.0"
```

So when running `react-native run-android` the Metro Bundler throws:

```
Looking for JS files in
   /Users/R01/Projects/RNApp
   /Users/R01/Projects/react-native-services 


Metro Bundler ready.

Loading dependency graph...(node:72824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: Sample
  Paths: /Users/R01/Projects/react-native-services/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Sample/package.json collides with /Users/R01/Projects/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Sample/package.json

 This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
    at setModule (/Users/R01/Projects/RNApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:446:17)
    at workerReply (/Users/R01/Projects/RNApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:496:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
(node:72824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:72824) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
error: bundling failed: Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: Sample
  Paths: /Users/R01/Projects/react-native-services/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Sample/package.json collides with /Users/R01/Projects/RNApp/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Sample/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
    at setModule (/Users/R01/Projects/RNApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:446:17)
    at workerReply (/Users/R01/Projects/RNApp/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:496:9)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:182:7)
```

I already tried:

- With both `npm` and `yarn`  (upgraded) installations but `react-native run-android` throws always the same error.
- watchman watch-del-all rm -rf node_modules && npm install rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-* npm cache clean npm start -- --reset-cache

Answer (score 1):

```
watchman watch-del-all

rm -rf node_modules && npm install

rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*
npm cache clean
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

[for more check out here](https://medium.com/@jeanjacquesbagui/react-native-providesmodule-naming-collision-error-6bc090925fb3)

Comment: heck i tried it twice and after second time it worked.. maybe the last command or idk

Comment: @Thakur, the above does not work for me because it will eventually create this directory `/ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive/Products/Applications/DEV.app/assets/node_modules/react-native/package.json` again when I go to generate `.ipa`.

Answer (score 1):

Faced same issue
Resolved it !!

All the npm packages in project have node modules.
Make sure that node_modules directory inside packages should not include already present node module.

In my case `react-native` was present in node_modules of my project as well as node_modules of another forked library.

As the library was forked, I could remove node_modules directory from it and the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I respond myself.

As a temporary solution, and given putting the dependencies in `peerDependencies` didn't work either, I've put the `react` and `react-native` in `devDependencies` of the `react-native-services` package.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error. I tried below steps, its works like a charming.

Please remove all react-native specific folders from "%appdata%\Temp" and then try below commands:

```
rimraf node_modules
npm cache clean --force
npm install
rm -rf ios/build
```

Change `/Users/Jebasuthan/XcodeProject/Game/ios/Pods/React/package.json` to something else

non recursive

[image: Xcode change]

Comment: I don't see a **Framework Search Paths**. What version of Xcode is that? My problem is I continue to get this directory generating `/ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive/Products/Applications/DEV.app/assets/node_modules/react-native/package.json` when creating an `.ipa`. which is conflicting with `/node_modules/react-native/package.json`

Comment: @Daniel My Xcode version is Version 10.3 (10G8). Try removing the '/ios/build/Archive/DEV.xcarchive/Products/Applications/DEV.app/assets/node_modules/react-native/package.json'

Comment: that's exactly what I ended up doing and it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
module.exports = {
 resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
        /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
    ])
 },
};
```