# Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:

Tags: android, react-native, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

I have created a custom `npm module` (will use **xxx** instead of its name) and link it manually using `npm install`.

I tried very hard and searched :

- [[Workarounds] Packager unable to resolve module from /Users/node_modules/](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968)
- [Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision when using a local dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905842/error-jest-haste-map-providesmodule-naming-collision-when-using-a-local-depen)

before raising a question. I would be thankful if someone tell me what wrong with my code or my approach or any error in my code.

When I run `react-native run-android` following error is raised by `metro bundler`

```
Error: jest-haste-map: Haste module naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: E:\cdg-native\CDG\node_modules\react-native-XXX\node_modules\react-native\package.json collides with E:\cdg-native\CDG\node_modules\react-native\package.json

This error is caused by `hasteImpl` returning the same name for different files.
```

My custom module `package.json` is

```
{
  "name": "react-native-xxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Library to render xxx",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react native xxx"
  ],
  "author": "Firdous Nath",
  "license": "ISC",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "*",
    "react-native": "*"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.6.1",
    "react-native": "^0.57.5",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1"
  }
}
```

`index.js` of the custom module is very simple as below

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

export default class XXXView extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Text> From custom module </Text>
        );
    }
}
```

file where I am using custom module is

```
import React from "react";
import {StyleSheet, View} from "react-native";
import XXXView from "react-native-xxx"
//import {XXXView} from "react-native-xxx" -> I tried this as well

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <XXXView/>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#f5fcff"
    }
});
```

I tried `npm install /absolute/path/to/xxx` and it linked module correctly. By correctly I mean I can see `react-native-xxx` package in `nodemodule` directory.
I did all possible ways but nothing worked.

I also tried but got no success

- yarn add /absolute/path/to/react-native-xxx
- react-native link react-native-xxx
- react-native run-android

Answer (score 7):

Add  **rn-cli.config.js** In the root project

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');
module.exports = {
 resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
        /node_modules\/.*\/node_modules\/react-native\/.*/,
    ])
 },
};
```

[see this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21242)

Hope it works for you

Comment: @luky do u use Pod?

Comment: @zhouDai, that solution does not work for me either.

Comment: @Daniel  do u use Pod?

Comment: @zhouDai, yes I do.

Comment: rn-cli.config.js doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @Daniel  add    'post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.name == "React"
      target.remove_from_project
    end
  end
end' at the end of the Podfile

Answer (score 4):

The error you get indicates that you have two `react-native` dependencies. One in your main project, one in your xxx module, thus creating a conflict between their `package.json`s. seems like if you install a package from a local path, it copies its `node_modules` directory.

As you already have `react-native` as peer dependency in your custom module's `package.json`, try removing `E:\cdg-native\CDG\node_modules\react-native-XXX\node_modules`, this should solve the conflict.

Comment: Thank you for your response but whenever I will run npm install node_modules will be created. If I publish the package others will get the same issue.

Comment: Actually, if the depency specified already exists in the project on which depends your custom module, it won't copy it in its own node_modules folder (at least it seems so). When I look at my react-native dep in node modules, I see it has a few deps in its node_modules folder, but the vast majority of them are in the project's modules folder

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a 2 different react-native project folders where one is dependent over another (it's getting included as node_module dependency) and it seems you are running your server start ("react-native start") command from the library folder.

Comment: Saved my day...was having another react-native project inside my project.Just deleted the unwanted one and boom!

Comment: lmao, i just realize i was start the server in node_modules folder