# How to resolve "Duplicate module name: react-native" using Expo

Tags: react-native, npm, expo

I keep getting the error below when using my own npm package, that also depends on `react-native`:

```
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
      Duplicate module name: react-native
      Paths: /reproducible-bug-examples/duplicate-module-name-npm/node_modules/react-native/package.json collides with /reproducible-bug-examples/duplicate-module-name/node_modules/react-native/package.json

    This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
```

The `package.json` for `duplicate-module-name-npm` is:

```
{
  "name": "duplicate-module-name-npm",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react": "16.5.0"
  },
}
```

For `duplicate-module-name`it is:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "node ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/samples": "2.1.1",
    "expo": "^32.0.0",
    "duplicate-module-name-npm": "file:../duplicate-module-name-npm",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-32.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-navigation": "^3.0.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^32.0.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I have tried the solution mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21242#issuecomment-445784118), i.e. adding a `rn-cli.config.js`, but the problem persists. Indeed, after adding the content described here I get the following error instead:

```
 (node:31392) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: react-native
  Paths: /reproducible-bug-examples/duplicate-module-name-npm/node_modules/react-native/package.json collides with /reproducible-bug-examples/duplicate-module-name/node_modules/react-native/package.json

This error is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
```

Also tried adding the following to `rn-cli-config.js`:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
      /duplicate-module-name-npm\/.*/,
    ])
  },
};
```

Repos with MWE are available at https://github.com/zxl634/duplicate-module-name-npm and https://github.com/zxl634/duplicate-module-name.

The error appears after running `expo start`.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated :)

Comment: You should modify the name of the package.json on one of them that they have react-native as a name. Change it for react-native2 for see if it that solve it if you want quick solution

Comment: Indeed,changing it in `duplicate-module-name-npm` and doing `rm -rf node_modules && npm i` seemed to fix it

Comment: Unfortunately, the solution didn't work because both need `react-native`and complains about not being able to find it if either is changed to e.g. ´react-native2`

Comment: Trying the solution mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905842/error-jest-haste-map-providesmodule-naming-collision-when-using-a-local-depen, i.e. putting `react` and `react-native` in `devDependencies` - however, didn't work

Comment: @FrancoCoronel, sorry, maybe I misunderstood you - do you mean to change the name of `package.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by a combination of adding paths to `rn-cli.config.js`:

```
const blacklist = require('metro-config/src/defaults/blacklist');

module.exports = {
  resolver: {
    blacklistRE: blacklist([
  /duplicate-module-name-npm\/node_modules\/react-native\/Libraries\/Sample\/.*/,
  /duplicate-module-name-npm\/node_modules\/react-native\/react-native-git-upgrade\/.*/,
  /duplicate-module-name-npm\/node_modules\/react-native\/react-native-cli\/.*/,
    ])
  },
};
```

And changing the "name" field in the package.json files that cause problems, e.g. `react-native/package.json`.